# Cannot save to file on Android and Apache Cordova 3.4.1

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova version: 3.4.1-0.1.0

I am using the file transfer plugin and I cannot save a image to file.

Errors I get from the device:
"download error target err"
upload error code 1

Here is the code, any ideas?

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(),
    d = new Date(),
    testImageUrl = encodeURI('http://www.inutritie.ro/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/otet-600x300.jpg'),
    imageCacheDir = '//Testdir';


fileTransfer.download(
    testImageUrl,
    'file:'+imageCacheDir+'/'+d.getTime(),
    function(entry){
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error){
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
);
```

Here is how I set and get the directory where I'll save the images on my Android device:

```
function initLocalCacheDir(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemFail);
};

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Testdir",{create:true, exclusive: false}, gotDir, gotDirError);
};

function gotDir(d) {
    var imageCacheDir = d.fullPath;
};

function gotDirError(evt) {
    alert('gotDirError');
};

function onFileSystemFail(evt) {
    alert('onFileSystemFail');
};
```

Comment: Does Testdir exist? Before you can save a file the directory you are saving it to must exist. It wont create it for you.